# Convert to multiple client server Connection

Tags: spring, spring-integration

making my previous question more readable, following is my code which works fine for single server single client connection, but i want my client to connect 2 or more servers dynamically,

```
     public class ClientCall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(GatewayConfig.class);
        GatewayService gatewayService = ctx.getBean(GatewayService.class);
        //int i=0;
        Message message = new Message();        
        /*while(i<4)
        {*/
            message.setPayload("It's working");
            gatewayService.sendMessage(message);
        /*  i++;            
        }*/

    }
}

public class Message {

    private String payload;
  // getter setter
}

@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gateway.service")
public class GatewayConfig {

    // @Value("${listen.port:6788}")
    private int port = 6785;

    @Autowired
    private GatewayService<Message> gatewayService;

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sendMessageChannel")
    public interface Gateway {
        void viaTcp(String payload);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientCF() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost",
                this.port);
        clientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        return clientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendMessageChannel")
    public MessageHandler tcpOutGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway outGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        outGateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        // outGateway.setAsync(true);
        outGateway.setOutputChannel(receiveMessageChannel());
        outGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
        outGateway.setReplyChannel(receiveMessageChannel());
        return outGateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sendMessageChannel() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        return channel;
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel receiveMessageChannel() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "receiveMessageChannel", outputChannel = "processMessageChannel")
    public String convert(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processMessageChannel")
    public void upCase(String response) {
        gatewayService.receiveMessage(response);
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "processMessageChannel")
    public void convertError(byte[] bytes) {
        String str = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("Error: " + str);
    }

}


public interface GatewayService<T> {

    public void sendMessage(final T payload);

    public void receiveMessage(String response);

}


@Service
public class GatewayServiceImpl implements GatewayService<Message> {

    @Autowired
    private Gateway gateway;

    @Autowired
    private GatewayContextManger<String, Object> gatewayContextManger;

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(final Message message) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gateway.viaTcp(message.getPayload());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(final String response) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message = new Message();
                message.setPayload(response);
                Object obj = gatewayContextManger.get(message.getPayload());
                synchronized (obj) {
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

and below is sever code similar there is another server with different port and ip then how to make connections to these servers?

```
class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6785);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence + "\r\n";
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments.

1. Instead of starting a thread to send the message, simply make `sendMessageChannel` an `ExecutorChannel`, using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` - it will be more efficient and gets you out of the business of managing threads.
2. If you only have 2 servers to connect to, rather than coming up with a dynamic scheme, simply define 2 TCP adapters and add a `@Router` after `sendMessageChannel`.
3. You can tell the router which server to send it to by setting a header.

   @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sendMessageChannel")
   public interface Gateway {
       void viaTcp(String payload @Header("which") String target);
   }

Use a `HeaderValueRouter` to route on header `which`.

See [Message Routing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html) in the reference manual.